# Preserve &reg; when using Bathisar Tidy on a Mac

Tags: html, macos, htmltidy

I just found Bathisar Tidy to tidy up HTML on a Mac.  Wonderful app but I cannot figure one thing out about it.  In my pages, where I have `&reg;` instead of the registered trademark symbol (®).  I want to preserve the `&reg;` in the documents. Bathisar Tidy replaces it with the symbol.

How do I prevent this?  What setting do I change?

TIA,
Linda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to type `&amp;reg;`

Comment: That would work but I would have to search and replace in hundreds of html files before using the tidy app.  What I was hoping for is to know which setting in Bathisar Tidy would prevent the replacement. It is definitely an option if this is not possible within the app itself.

Comment: I don't know for the app you use but several softwares allow to search & replace strings in an entire set of documents like dreamweaver or notepad++